# Get the indicies of a dataframe to use on a list

Tags: python, python-2.7, indexing, pandas

I am trying to extract elements of a list based on the contents of a pandas dataframe.This is probably best explained through an example:

Say I have a list of lists called a

```
a = [['Lazy', 'Brown', 'Fox'], ['Jumps', 'Over'], ['Big', 'Blue', 'Sea']]
```

and a pandas dataframe called `df` in the form of

```
Name    Group
A         1
B         1
C         2
```

I want to index list `a` based on the Group variable in `df`. So I would have a result

```
[['Lazy', 'Brown', 'Fox', 'Jumps', 'Over'], ['Big', 'Blue', 'Sea']]
```

Or something similar.

I am more used to using R to code, in which this process would be relatively straight forward - so I am hoping that is also the case in python, but I haven't found anything that will help me solve this problem in python yet.

Comment: how does `[['Lazy', 'Brown', 'Fox', 'Jumps', 'Over'], ['Big', 'Blue', 'Sea']]` come about?

Comment: Because they are both in Group 1 in df.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could express this as a [groupby/agg operation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#aggregation):

```
import pandas as pd
a = [['Lazy', 'Brown', 'Fox'], ['Jumps', 'Over'], ['Big', 'Blue', 'Sea']]
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':list('ABC'), 'Group':[1,1,2]})
df['a'] = a
print(df.groupby(['Group'])['a'].sum())
```

yields

```
Group
1    [Lazy, Brown, Fox, Jumps, Over]
2                   [Big, Blue, Sea]
Name: a, dtype: object
```

Aggregation by summing works because the sum of two lists is a concatenated list:

```
In [322]: ['Lazy', 'Brown', 'Fox'] + ['Jumps', 'Over']
Out[322]: ['Lazy', 'Brown', 'Fox', 'Jumps', 'Over']
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. I didn't realise a list could be added to a pandas data frame as a single column.